# Order by case with over 2 when conditions in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try this query below, for sort the `table1` with `ORDER BY CASE` and `5 WHEN CONDITIONS`  and got an unexpected results. It's seem that the `WHEN condition number 2, 3 and 4` do not work. I don't know what is wrong here and need help? Thanks very much!

```
SELECT s.so_id, t.affiliate_id, t.aff_priority, t.priority_type
FROM table1 s
LEFT JOIN table2 f ON f.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t ON t.affiliate_id = f.affiliate_id
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN t.is_active = 1 THEN 0
    WHEN t.aff_priority IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    WHEN t.priority_type = 1 THEN 2
    WHEN t.priority_type = 2 THEN 3
    WHEN t.priority_type = 3 THEN 4 END,
    t.aff_priority DESC, s.so_id DESC
```

Comment: What did you expect to get?  What did you get instead?

Comment: run the case in the select and see what all columns have as value adapt it and go on

Comment: @jjanes I expect that all records has `priority_type = 1` must be before `priority_type = 2`, and so on. But the result instead just sort by the `aff_priority DESC`.

Comment: I would only expect that would only be within records where is_active is distinct from 1 and where aff_priority is NULL.  Please show actual inputs and outputs, not hand-wavy descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

As I have known, the correct order condition is below. I hope it can help you.

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.is_active = 1 THEN t.is_active END ASC,
    CASE WHEN t.aff_priority IS NOT NULL THEN t.aff_priority END ASC,
    CASE WHEN t.priority_type = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN t.priority_type = 2 THEN 2
    WHEN t.priority_type = 3 THEN 3 END ASC,
    t.aff_priority DESC, 
    s.so_id DESC
```